# Does skaffold respect rolling updates?

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold

Does skaffold respect rolling updates when the `--force` option is used? When I execute `skaffold run --force` with

```
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 3
```

It seems that surge never occurs.

In another terminal window I run `watch kubectl get pods` and I never see the number of replicas for my deployment go above 3. I suspect this is because of the `--force` flag but I'm not sure.

Before people tell me to not use force, see https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/3171. Skaffold automatically changes the run-id which causes deployments to fail if resources for the deployment already exist. That being said, if there's a way to tell skaffold to update a deployment without complaining about mismatched run-ids, I'd love to hear. I'm not a fan of using `--force`.

EDIT:

Looking at the skaffold help I see:

```
      --force=false: Recreate Kubernetes resources if necessary for deployment, warning: might cause downtime! (true by default for `skaffold dev`)
```

The `Recreate` word suggests that the RollingDeployment strategy might not be respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more testing I can confirm that using `--force` causes the deployment strategy to ignored. To get around the run-id problem I mentioned I

1. Did a force deployment with `-l skaffold.dev/run-id=test`
2. Did another deployment without `--force` and with the same run-id from the previous step.

When I did this I saw the surge I expected.